# number of server round trips in client statistics is 3 for a simple command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I do this:

```
Select * from Person
```

number of server round trips in client statistics  is 3 for a simple command.number of server round trips means Number of times the driver sent commands to the server and received a reply.why it's 3?it shouldn't be 1?

Comment: SQL is just an abstract language standard. I doubt that it defines how many server round trips are required for requests. This is implementation-specific; what RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.)? Please add a tag to your question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about? And how many rows does the statement return?

Comment: sql server2014 and no row

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on this part.But following might be 3 round trips in this case:
1. Open connection/check for opened connection
2. Execute Command and return result
3. Close connection

Comment: OR there are 3 roundtrips because the result set is huge and is fetched in 3 batches. OR (any other implementation-specific reason or quirk). Without knowing the exact data & RDBMS, we have to guess.